# Setting up Visual Studio with Meson

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, meson-build

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio with a Meson build system.

For this I'm using an Make file project as described in https://mesonbuild.com/Vs-External.html

Which works to build the solution, however when trying to run the project, it cannot start as some DLL ( build by the project ) cannot be found. This is because when building Meson does not but dependent DLL next to the executable.

I can manually start the executable generated in the build directory using `meson devenv main.exe` however I can't seem to 'convince' Visual Studio to use the Meson devenv when launching the executable.

**Q:** How do I properly setup Visual studio and Meson to work together?

I will add that *"just use static libraries"* is not a valid solution.